# Bokeh 0.12.4 to 0.12.5 -- property GlyphRenderer.muted_glyph wasn't declared

Tags: bokeh

I have an interesting issue with an upgrade from 0.12.4 to 0.12.5 in Bokeh.

The code creating Bokeh charts running on Flask is fairly simple --

```
bk_sector_betas = Bar(sector_betas)
bk_sector_betas_script, bk_sector_betas_div = components(bk_sector_betas)
return render_template('main.html', 
    bk_sector_betas_script=bk_sector_betas_script, bk_sector_betas_div=bk_sector_betas_div)
```

And in Jinja2 ..

```
{{ bk_sector_betas_script|indent(4)|safe }}
{{ bk_sector_betas_div|indent(4)|safe }}
```

This works perfectly fine in Bokeh 0.12.4, but in 0.12.5, I get the following error --

```
Bokeh Error: property GlyphRenderer.muted_glyph wasn't declared
```

I tried this on PythonAnywhere, Windows and Mac (using both conda and base Python) and each time, it was changing from 0.12.4 to 0.12.5 that made the difference. I have downgraded back down to 0.12.4 for my application, but was wondering what I might need to change for the latest version of Bokeh.

Answer (score 9):

Almost certainly the case that you need to update the links to the CDN versions of BokehJS in your HTML template. If you are running (Python) Bokeh 0.12.5, then we web page has to load BokehJS 0.12.5 as well.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this answer solved it for me.